# Issue with sql query with count variable

Tags: sql, odbc

I have this query here:

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT id(*) AS count FROM forma";
$result_pag_num = odbc_exec($connection, $$query_pag_num) or die(odbc_error());
```

I get this error though:

```
Undefined variable: SELECT id(*) AS count FROM forma in
```

Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks..

I get an error about the id here:

```
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is invaid syntax.  `id(*)` is not something defined that's why the error. Proper way would be

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT count(id) AS myCount FROM forma";
```

And why do you have two `$$` here? That makes it a variable variable

```
$result_pag_num = odbc_exec($connection, $$query_pag_num) or die(odbc_error());
                                          ^
```

It has to be

```
$result_pag_num = odbc_exec($connection, $query_pag_num) or die(odbc_error());
```

[Read](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks.. i still get this: Undefined variable: SELECT count(id) AS count FROM forma

Comment: Thanks, it removed most of the errors, it did, i just get this one now :  Undefined index: id in

Comment: Lol then you do not have id field in your table

Comment: if you fetch something like `count(id) a myCount` then you grab it like `$row['myCount']` and not like `$row['id']`